# ZK Bandbox Listbox autoPaging problems with filtering

Tags: java, listbox, zk

i have a bandBox using ZK 5.0.8(M.V.C Approach) inside is a listbox which shows the records later i filters the results onChanging in the bandBox eventListener[event] but sometimes the pageSize and paging is out of Sync with the results on the listbox sometimes is NOT records on IT(0 matches) an still showing

```
 1/ 13[ 1 - 4 / 51]
```

why is this?? can somebody give me a hint. here is my relevant code

```
<bandbox id="bandforcode" autodrop="true" width="270px">    
<listbox id="listBoxForCode" height="250px" width="300px" mold="paging" autopaging="true">
 public void setListBoxForBandBoxFromDB(Listbox box,String ref)//Filtering
 {     
   final ArrayList<Student>students = new ArrayList<Student>(manager.getListForStudentsByRefBandBox(ref));     
   box.getItems().removeAll(box.getItems());       
   BindingListModelList model = new BindingListModelList(students,false);
   box.setModel(model);
}
box.addEventListener("onChanging",new EventListener()//Listener
{
    public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception
    {                       
    final Bandbox band = (Bandbox)event.getTarget();
    final org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.InputEvent inputEvent=(org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.InputEvent)event;              
    final String initialText = inputEvent.getValue();                                  

setListBoxForBandBoxFromDB((Listbox)band.getFirstChild().getFirstChild(),initialText);                          
     }
});
```

please take a look to the image below.

[Screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/95199877@N03/8677215545/in/photostream)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not all relevant code.
Please. post the every method belongs to the filter process.

Answer (score 0):

I tink the problem could be this

```
box.getItems().removeAll(box.getItems());
```

You should not edit the `Items` when using a `Model`.

Change it to

```
box.getModel().clear();
```

or just delet the line, cos you set a new model anyway.